# How to use texture compression in openGL?

Tags: opengl, image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm making an image viewer using openGL and I've run into a situation where I need to load very large (>50MB) images to be viewed.  I'm loading the images as textures and displaying them to a GL_QUAD which has been working great for smaller images, but on the large images the loading fails and I get a blank rectangle.  So far I've implemented a very ugly hack that uses another program to convert the images to smaller, lower resolution versions which can be loaded, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.  I've found that openGL has a [texture compression feature](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_compression.txt) but I can't get it to work. When I call

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ARB, t.width(), t.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.bits());
```

I get the compiler error "*GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ARB* undeclared".  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a library I'm missing?  And more generally, is this a viable solution to my problem?

I'm using Qt Creator on a Windows Vista machine, with a NVIDIA Quadro FX 1700 graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my own GFX card the maximum resolution for an opengl texture is 8192x8192, if your image is bigger then 50MB, it is propably a very very high resolution...
Check http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm , it describes how you can find the maximum texture size.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd have to ask what resolution are these large images? Secondly, to use a define such as GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_ARB, you would need to download and use something like GLEW which is more modernized in the GL api than the standard MS-Dev install.

Comment: The images are anywhere between 10,000 and 30,000 pixels per side.

Comment: Yeah, your card's drivers most likely can't handle that resolution, so you are best to split them up into smaller images.